# Parsing ODF in Python with lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, odf

I'm trying to parse the content.xml inside a ODF-file. I've read the file into a string and i've got a tree object with lxml.etree:

```
tree = etree.XML(string)
```

But now I need to find every subelement that is text:a OR text:h. I've been told in previous question that I could use XPath. I've tried but got stuck every single time. Can't even find one of those elements.

If i try:

```
elem = tree.xpath('//text:p')
```

I just get a

```
XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix
```

So how do I get a list with BOTH of thoose subelements in the right order so i can iterate over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `text` is a namespace abbreviation, defined in the [ODF schema](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.1/OS/OpenDocument-schema-v1.1.rng). Try

```
tree.xpath('//text:a | //text:h',
           namespaces={'text': 'urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0'})
```

`|` is the set union operator. See also [LXML docs](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes).

Comment: Great! Thnx. Now, how do I get an OR statement in there so it fetch both text:p and text:h ?

Comment: Ah yes, forgot that. Added it to the answer now.

Comment: I could just have found that by google "xpath operators". So sorry for not trying. But I was really frustrated last night. Thanks alot anyway! :)

Comment: @larsmans: `|` is the XPath union operator: not an "or" operator. XPath has `or` operator. `|` is a set operator (its arguments must be node-sets) while `or` is a boolean operator -- its arguments must be booleans. As it is possible to convert almost any type to boolean, it just happens so that `or` can be used with almost any types of arguments (the conversions to booleans are done automatically), so it is possible to have the expression `$node-set1 or $node-set2`, however the result is just a boolean - `true()`/`false()`. `|` only operates on nodesets and its result is a nodeset.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: sorry for the confusion, but I'm used to conflating set union and disjunction (studied too much logic in my life :). Fixed the answer now.